# How to use Objects.function if Objectsname is taken from String

Tags: string, flash, object, button, actionscript-2

I was wondering if this concept is doable:

Scenario:
4 areas on 1 stage which are quite similar (eg webcamconference, each area has the same functions)

Buttonobjects are numbered(eg area 1 has playbutton1,mutebutton1,namebutton1,namelabel1, etc)

every area gets a close-Button which closes/shuts down the area.(close1,close2,close3...)

i want to archive the following:

```
if(close1.isPressed){
function invisall(1);
}

/*
 * instead of writing
 * if(close1.isPressed){
 * playbutton1._visible=false;
 * mutebutton1._visible=false;
 * }else if(close2.isPressed){
 * playbutton2._visible=false;
 * mutebutton2._visible=false;
 * etc. resulting in an enormous block.

 * the interesting part. buttonNr gets added via String to become a real buttonname(eg
 * playbutton1 as mentioned above).*/

function invisall(int buttonNr){
String newPlayButtonObjectName="playbutton"+buttonNr;
newPlayButtonObjectName._visible=false;

String newMuteButton="mutebutton"+buttonNr;
newMuteButton._visible=false;
}

this should do the trick via dynamic Nr at the end of each default button(eg
playbutton)
but ofc
"playbutton1"._visible=false;
doesnt work because playbutton1 is still a String.
how can i take the String as a Buttonname/ButtonObject?
do i need to write an new function? this would destroy the purpose of less code.
```

maybe u like this idea. for now i will split the area into frames that i put on the stage. that should help.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function invisall(int buttonNr){
  this["playbutton"+buttonNr]._visible=false;
  this["mutebutton"+buttonNr]._visible=false;
}
```

I hope this is what you want.